Can a heretic be a Guru of Aryan?
Many Gurus today believe that Buddhism Jainism Hinduism and all religions lead to same Goal..but Manu smriti states that only Vedic darshana is true and all other darshanas are false..Can such a(believer in heresy) person initiate a Dwija? Can he be called a Guru?
Or a person who believes in improper philosophy be called a Guru?

You mean "improper philosophy" as which is antagonist to Hinduism?

I) Your first question Many Gurus today believe that Buddhism Jainism Hinduism and all religions lead to same Goal
Sankara censors both Buddhism and Jainism as follows:
a) Within Buddhism (at the time Ādi Shankarāchārya), there are four doctrinal schools:


Vaibhāsika (वैभाषिक/Direct Realism).
Sautrāntika (सौत्रांतिक/Representationalism/Hīnayāna).
Vijnānavāda (विज्ञानवाद/aka Yogācāra-योगाचार/Subjective Idealism).
Sūnyavāda (शून्यवाद/aka
Madhyamika-मध्यमिका/Voidism/nihilism/Mahāyāna/Denying the existence
of everything).

Please refer Brahma Sūtra Bhāsyam from [II.ii.18] to [II.ii.32] for Sankara’s
refutation of those four schools based Philosophy of Buddhism.

b) Jain Criticism:

The Jain theory of Karma has been challenged from an early time by the
Vedanta and Sāṃkhya branches of Hindu philosophy. In particular,
Vedanta Hindus considered the Jain position on the supremacy and
potency of karma, specifically its insistence on non-intervention by
any Supreme Being in regard to the fate of souls, as nāstika or
atheistic. For example, in a commentary to the Brahma Sutras (III, 2,
38, and 41), Adi Sankara argues that the original karmic actions
themselves cannot bring about the proper results at some future time;
neither can super sensuous, non-intelligent qualities like adrsta—an
unseen force being the metaphysical link between work and its
result—by themselves mediate the appropriate, justly deserved pleasure
and pain. The fruits, according to him, then, must be administered
through the action of a conscious agent, namely, a supreme being
(Isvara).
-Wiki

II) Your second question but Manu smriti states that only Vedic darshana is true and all other darshanas are false..Can such a(believer in heresy) person initiate a Dwija? Can he be called a Guru?
Answer is Yes.
(1) Sreemad Bhagavatham [Canto-4, Chapter-1, Verse-33] says Dattâtreya as a very powerful yogi (Yoga-vit/योगवित्) by birth.

सोमोऽभूद्ब्रह्मणोंऽशेन दत्तो विष्णोस्तु योगवित् ।
दुर्वासा: शङ्करस्यांशो निबोधाङ्गिरस: प्रजा: ॥ ४.१.३३ ॥

Thereafter, from the partial representation of Brahmā, the moon-god
was born of them; from the partial representation of Viṣṇu, the
great mystic [योगवित्/Yoga-vit] Dattātreya was born; and from the partial representation of Śaṅkara [Lord Śiva], Durvāsā was born.
॥ 4.1.33 ॥

(2) Markandeya purana [Canto XVII] says that the Prajāpati Atri begot three sons by his wife Anasūyā, namely, Soma, Dattātreya, and Durvāsas, who were incarnations of portions of Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Śiva respectively [Slokas: 86-103].
Dattātreya(दत्तात्रेय), as a yogi, appears to adopt unorthodox Vāmāchāra Mārgam (वामाचार मार्गम्/வாமாச்சார மார்க்கம்/Left-hand path) expressed in the following slokas [107-115]:

दत्तात्रेयो$पि विषयान्योगस्थो ददृशे हरिः। 
दुर्वासाः पितर त्यक्त्वा मातर चोत्तम व्रतम्‌॥ १०७॥ 
उन्मत्ताख्य समाश्रित्य परिबभ्राम मेदिनीम्‌ 

Dattatreya also, being Visnu, enjoyed objects of sense while engaged
in profound meditation Durvasas, deeming his father and mother to be
the chiefest object of devotion, assuming the form known as
'frantic,’ roamed about the earth
मुनिपुत्रवृतों योगी दत्तात्रेयोऽप्यसङ्गित्ताम्‌॥ १० ८॥
अभीप्समानः सरसि निममज्ज चिर विभुः। 
तथापि त महात्मानमतीव प्रियदर्शनम्‌॥ १० ९॥
तत्यजुर्न कुमारास्ते सरसस्तीरसश्रयाः

Surrounded by the sons of Munis, the lordly yogi Dattatreya also,
desirous of obtaining exemption from all attachments, long Immersed
himself in a lake Nevertheless those youths, resorting to the bank of
the lake, did not forsake him, who was magnanimous and exceedingly benign.
दिव्ये वर्षशते पूर्णे यदा तेन त्यजन्ति तम्‌॥ ११०॥ 
तत्प्रीत्या सरसस्तीर सर्वे मुनिकुमारकाः।
ततो दिव्याम्बरधरा सुरूपा सुनितम्बिनीम्‌॥ १११॥
नारीमादाय कल्याणीमुत्ततार जलान्मुनिः। 
स्त्रोसन्निकर्षिण होते परित्यक्ष्यन्ति मामिति॥ ११२॥
मुनिपुत्रास्ततो योगे स्थास्यामीति विचिन्तयन्‌

When after a hundied heavenly years were ended, all those youthful
Munts, through affection for him, still forsook not the bank of the
lake, the Muni, taking his noble wife clothed ın heavenly raiment,
beautiful and plump ın form, arose trom the water, thinking, If these
sons or Munis shall forsake me because of the presence of a woman,
then I will remain free from all attachments.
तथापि ते मुनिसुता न त्यजन्ति यदा मुनिम्‌॥ ११३॥
तत. सह तया नार्या मद्यपानमथाकरोत्‌। 
सुरापानरत तेन सभार्य तत्यजुस्ततः॥ ११४॥ 
गीतवाद्यादिवनिताभोगससर्गदूषितम्‌।
मन्यमाना महात्मान तया सह बहिष्क्रियम्‌॥ ११५॥

When nevertheless the sons of the Munis did not torsake him, he next
drank intoxicating liquors in company with his wife Thereupon they did
not forsake him, though he was engrossed in drinking spirituous liquor
in company with his wife, and though he was rendered impure by
addiction to singing, musical instruments and such like, and also by
intercourse with his wife; deeming that the high-souled Muni when with
her was detached from religious rites.

The following two slokas identify Dattātreya(दत्तात्रेय) as the lord of yogis [slokas: 116-117]:

नावाप दोषं योगीशो वारुणीं स पिबन्नपि।
अन्तावसायिवेश्मान्तर्मातरिश्वा स्पृशन्निवा  ॥ ११६॥
सुरां पिबन्सपत्नीकस्तपस्तेपे स योगवित्‌।
योगीश्वरश्जिन्त्यमानो यागिभिर्मुक्तिकांक्षिभिः ॥ ११७॥

The lord of yogis, although drinking spirituous liquor, incurred no
fault. Dwelling like Mátarisvan within the abodes of candalas,
drinking strong drink he, skilled in yoga, the lord of yogis, attended
by his wife, performed austerities, being meditated on by yogis who
longed for deliverance from mundane existence.

Unlike Rishis, look at his conduct that He carried out Himself unorthodoxly and followed activities similar to Vāmāchāra Mārgam (वामाचार मार्गम्/Left-hand path); particularly, this has attracted Sanniyasi Sanghas and titled him as Guru of the Yogis; refer slokas 116 and 117 as described above that corroborates scripturally these words.
(3) In Narada Purana [Chapater-76], Rishi Sanathkumara told Devarishi Narada about Kartaviryarjuna, who was the avatara of Sudarsana Cakra, in the following three slokas [3-5]:

Listen O Narada, to what I shall say for dispelling your doubts and as
to how Kartavirya has attained the status of one worthy of being
served.॥ 3 ॥
He was the incarnation of Sudaréana Cakra on the earth. After
propitiating Dattatreya he attained excellent brilliance. ॥ 4 ॥
O Narada, by the mere remembrance of that leading king one is able to
conquer enemies in the battle and immediately get back what is lost. ॥
5 ॥

(4) Srimad Bhagavatam [Book-9, chapter 23, verses: 23-27] says a few lines about Arjuna (he was the son of Kritavirya and hence called Kartaviryarjuna), who accomplished Ashta Siddhi of Yoga form Guru Dattâtreya,  in the verses as given here [slokas: 23-24].

दुर्मदो भद्रसेनस्य धनकः कृतवीर्यसूः ।
कृताग्निः कृतवर्मा च कृतौजा धनकात्मजाः ॥ २३ ॥
Durmada and Dhanaka were the sons begotten by Bhadrasena, and Dhanaka
gave life to the sons Kritavîrya, Kritâgni, Kritavarmâ and Kritaujâ. ॥
23 ॥
अर्जुनः कृतवीर्यस्य सप्तद्वीपेश्वरोऽभवत् ।
दत्तात्रेयात् हरेरंशात् प्राप्तयोगमहागुणः ॥ २४ ॥
From Kritavîrya there was Arjuna [Kârtavîryârjuna] who became emperor
over the seven continents. From Lord Dattâtreya, an [amsa] incarnation
of the Supreme Personality, he obtained all the great qualities [the
eight siddhis] of yoga.  ॥ 24 ॥

(5) Brahmanda Purana [Section 3 - Upodghāta-pāda, Chapter-69] says about birth of Kārttavīrya and the boons received for Yogi Dattâtreya as follows:

Kanaka’s heirs were four and they were very famous in all the worlds.
They were Kṛtavīrya, Kṛtāgni, Kṛtavarman and Kṛtaujas who was the
fourth. Arjuna was the son of Kṛtavīrya. This king became the
overlord of seven continents with a thousand hands. ॥ 8-9 ॥
Kārttavīrya performed penance for ten thousand years. His penance was
extremely difficult to be performed. By means of this penance, he
propitiated Yogi Dattâtreya.॥ 10 ॥
Yogi Dattâtreya granted him four excellently glorious boons.॥ 11-13 ॥
 1. He chose at the out-set the first boon viz. a thousand arms.
 2. (His second boon was) the ability to prevent one from evil the
    moment he plans (lit. meditates upon) it.
 3. His third boon was protection of the Earth virtuously after
    conquering it righteously.
 4. His last boon was “I must be able to conquer in many battles. I must
    kill thousands of enemies. My death should be in a battle while
    fighting.”

-Brahmanda Purana [Upodghāta-pāda, Chapter-69, slokas: 8-13]

(5) Vishnu Purana [Book-4, Chapter-11] says about Kārttavīrya defeating Lankāpati Rāvana as follows:

While sporting in the waters of the Narmada and elevated with wine,
dasakanta Rāvana came on his tour of triumph to the city Mahismati and
there he who boasted of overthrowing the gods, the Daityas, the
Gandharvas and their king, was taken prisoner by Kārttavīrya and
confined like a tame beast in a corner of his capitol.॥ 6 ॥

Kārttavīrya's all of these Parākrama(पराक्रम) were the blessing of his Guru Dattâtreya!
Conclusion:
Heretic means (in religion) a person who holds religious beliefs in conflict with official dogma. Yogic Guru Dattâtreya activities were never agreeing with dharma sastras in vogue; He enjoyed objects of senses and addiction to singing, musical instruments and such like, and also by intercourse with his wife;  he also drank intoxicating liquors in company with his wife; Dwelling within the abodes of candālās; he was detached from religious rites against asserted by dharma sastras. However, as high-souled Muni, he was hailed as Lord of Gurus by both dvijas(द्विज) and non-dvijas (अद्विज) equally.

Kulārnava Tantra (कुलार्णव तंत्र) says about qualifications of Guru who is eligible to perform Mantra Dīksha (मन्त्र दीक्षा) to a shisya for Tantra Sādhana [13:72].
At the same time, Kulārnava Tantra [13:127-129], describes six kinds of Gurus and as long as one being a Bhodaka, he is eligible for a Guru to do upadesam for ātmajnāna (leads to liberation).
Any body can be a Guru, even if he is a Caṇḍāla, as supported by Ādi Śaṅkarācārya.

According to Sri Shankara Digvijayam [Ch-5], Ādi
Śaṅkarācārya(आदि शङ्कराचार्य), was on his way to the Kashi Visvanatha
temple, after finishing his bath in Ganga, when he came across a
Caṇḍāla(चण्डाल) and his four dogs. He asked the Caṇḍāla to move away
from him, as was the custom in those days, to which the Caṇḍāla
questioned him in two Sanskrit verses:
अन्नमायादन्नमयमथवा चैतन्यमेव चैतन्यात्य। तिवर दूरीकर्तुं वाञ्छसि किं ब्रूहि गच्छगच्छेति॥

To move matter from matter, or to separate spirit from Spirit?
O best among the twice born, which of these two do you wish to achieve by 
saying, “Move away, move away”?

Astonished Śaṅkarācārya replied to the questions in five verses, known
as Manīshā Panchakam (मनीषा पंचकम्), and touched the feet of
caṇḍāla, as a way to show respect him as a Guru!


III) Your third and final question Or a person who believes in improper philosophy be called a Guru?
Can you call a Guru who is a believer of improper philosophy as heretic? Answer is No, because heretic means, as far as I understand, conflict with accepted beliefs and canons of a philosophy.
Guru Dattâtreya was in conflict with canons and beliefs of dharma sastras however he was a highly evolved yogi with accomplishment of Ashta Siddhi which was demonstrated aptly by his ardent disciple Kartaviryarjuna who was a kshatriya. As mentioned before in Markandeya purana, āryans (sons of munis) were following him, thus establishing him as lord of yogis.
So a heretic can not only be a Guru but also a Guru of Āryans!

Note: The question is very generic. This answer is specific to Vedantic Gurus only.
Short answer: A heretic cannot be a Vedantic Guru.
The qualities of a Vedantic Guru are mentioned in Mundaka Upanishad 1.2.12.

parīkṣya lokānkarmacitānbrāhmaṇo nirvedamāyānnāstyakṛtaḥ kṛtena |
tadvijñānārthaṃ sa gurumevābhigacchetsamitpāṇiḥ śrotriyaṃ brahmaniṣṭham || 12 ||



Let a Brahmin having examined the worlds produced by karma be free from desires, thinking, ‘there is nothing eternal produced by karma?; and in order to acquire the knowledge of the eternal, let him Samid (sacrificial fuel) in hand, approach a perceptor (preceptor?) alone, who is versed in the Vedas and centered in the Brahman.


The Guru must be shrotriya and brahmanishta.
Sri Adi Shankara explains these terms in his commentary and also lists other qualities of a Guru.

Thus disgusted, the Brahmin should, for knowing that abode which is fearless, full of bliss, not made, and eternal, only approach a preceptor, possessing attributes such as control of mind, control of the external senses and mercy, etc., (the force of the word ‘alone’ is to show that even one versed in the recital of the sastras should not independently by himself seek the knowledge of the Brahman) with a load of Samid in his hand.


Srotriyam,’ versed in the recital of the Vedas and the knowledge of its import. ‘Brahmanishtham’; like japanishtha and taponishtha, this word means ‘one who is centred in the Brahman devoid of attributes and without a second, after renouncing all karma; for, one performing karma cannot be centred in the Brahman on account of the antagonism between karma and the knowledge of the Atman.

It is very clear from the above that VedAntic Guru cannot be a heretic as heretics deny the existence of brahman/Atman.
